# Live server not displayes html and css code correctly,while opening with file does

Tags: html, css, liveserver

I have encountered a problem with the Live server, Live server does not display HTML and CSS properly while opening with File does.
I checked the code but it seems that code hasn't the problem. Is there any bug? because I tried restarting VS code and reinstalling the Live server extension, but it doesn't work.

On the first picture is opened with the file (As it should display), But on the second is opened with the live server, U can clearly see differences.

[image: This is opened with the file (As it should display)]

[image: This is opened with the live server, U can clearly see differences.]

Thank you.

Comment: Check your browser console and network tabs. Are the stylesheet(s) being loaded correctly? Are those resources cached? Did you try clearing the cache?

Comment: Thank you for your time, I changed the chrome magnifier to 100% and it fixed the problem. I'm still new to HTML and CSS.